# Design ideas for cooperative stream consumers?

Tags: java, design-patterns, stream

Suppose the following scenario:

We have a Java class from some library that consumes a stream of bytes, say some XML parser `XmlParser1` which exposes a method `xmlParser1.parse(inputStream)`; the method, as it's typical, eats all bytes in a single call, eventually blocking.
We also have another class, from some other library, that does something similar, with a different implementation: `XmlParser2` with  `xmlParser2.parse(inputStream)`. 
Now, we want to **parse a single stream** with both parsers.

My first answer would be: we're screwed. As we cannot control how each class consumes the stream, all we can do is buffering all bytes in memory or to a temporary file (or open/reopen it, if possible). The API of those consumers are inherently non cooperative.

Now, suppose we have control on `XmlParser1` (implementation and signature) and we want to code it in a more flexible and cooperative way, so that a caller can implement the above behaviour in some reasonable and efficient way... what would you suggest?

Some alternatives I've considering:

1) Make `XmlParser1` implement `FilterInputStream`, so that when some class (`XmlParser1`) attemps to read some bytes from it, it internally parses what it has to (iteratively, perhaps with some reasonable buffering) and also returns the raw bytes. (This does not correspond exactly to the `FilterInputStream` concept, I'd say). In this way, the client code could chain the parsers simply:

```
   public class XmlParser1 extends FilterInputStream {
       public XmlParser1(InputStream rawInputStream) { ... } 
       public int read(byte[] b, int off, int l) throws IOException {
           // this would invoke the underlying stream read, parse internall the read bytes,
           // and leave them in the buffer
       }
   }

   XmlParser1 parser1 = new XmlParser1(inputstream);
   XmlParser2 parser2 = new XmlParser2(parse); 
   parser2.parse(); // parser2 consumes all the input stream, which causes parser1 to read an parse it too
```

2) Instead of regarding at `XmlParser1` as a **consumer** of bytes, regard it as  a **sink**: we won't let it eat itself the bytes, we'll spoon-feed it. So, instead of `xmlParser1.parse(inputStream)` we could have 
`xmlParser1.write(byte[])` ... that is, instead of passing it an `InputStream` we'll make it an `OutputStream`. This would allow a client to create a TeeInputStream that passes the bytes transparently to the `XmlParser2` class and that, simultaneously, calls `XmlParser1.write()`

Notice that we don't need separate threads in any case.

I'm not sure which one (if anyone) is conceptually preferable, of if there are better alternatives. It sounds to me as a design problem that should have been already discussed, but I haven't find much - not necessarily restricted to Java. Opinions and references are welcomed.

Comment: Check PipeInputStream/PipeOutputStream classes as well.

Comment: What do you think of my answer? I'm just asking, because I provided you with the cleanest solution: Making objects out of streams, and then work with the objects. But I also know another solution, let's say a "workaround", which I don't regard as best implementation, only as a possible one. Still, I don't know why you want to parse the same stream more than once, since this costs CPU power. However, I also don't know your implementation, there may exist some rare special cases where doing this is appropriate. Can you tell us a little more? Why do you want to parse the same stream two times?

Comment: @Marcus: suppose I prefer XmlParser2, but XmlParser1 gives me some accesory information. My concrete case: I have a PngReader2 that I want to use (because it gives me directly my desired image format) but also a PngReader1 that parses metadata, and I want both things.

Comment: @leonbloy: Is there anything wrong with my answer? And with what kind of solution did you end up with? It would be great if you tell us about your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the two parsers are running in two separate threads, it could be like this (not a working code)

```
public class Test extends FilterInputStream {
    byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
    int len;
    Thread thread = null;

    @Override
    public synchronized int read(byte[] b, int off, int l) throws IOException {
        while (thread == Thread.currentThread() && len > 0) {
            thread.wait();
        }
        if (len > 0) {
            System.arraycopy(buf, 0, b, off, l);
            len = 0;
            return l;
        }
        len = super.read(b, off, l);
        System.arraycopy(b, off, buf, 0, len);
        thread = Thread.currentThread();
        notify();
        return len;
    }
```

that is, #1 reads bytes and saves them in buf, next attempt by #1 is blocked until #2 reads all from buffer

Answer (score 1):

If your threads are on the same server, your idea to split the InputStreams won't make any sense. Because you'll still use only one InputStream and one BufferedInputStream to get the data, create the objects out of the InputStreams, and then you use those objects in the two different running threads. Conclusion: *There is never a necessity to block any InputStream at any time in Java.* I would even consider it harmful, because if you block, what happens if your buffer - or pipe - flows over? A queue overflow!

(**EDIT:** If you want to stop a stream, you need to tell the sender not to send any data any more. Or you do it like youtube, they slice a video into parts (i.e. 1 part for 1 minute) and only preload those parts at once, so stopping the video won't affect the preloading at all, since it only preaload if you reach a certain position in the timeline (like on 45 seconds, 1 minute 45 seconds, 2 minute 45 seconds, aso). Well, this is actually only a preloading technique and no real streaming, that's why Youtube doesn't need to mess with packet drops.)

However, I still have a few lines of pseudo code for you, the client:

```
BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(/*yourBasicInputStream*/);
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);  //Or use another wrapper
oos.writeObject(yourObjectToSend);      //Or use another parser: Look into the API: ObjectInputStream
```

The class variables within the main thread controller (aka server):

```
Thread thread1;  //e.g. a GUI controller
Thread thread2;  //e.g. a DB controller
```

The server (or another server thread started by the server, with both thread as parameters):

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(/*yourBasicInputStream*/);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);   //Or use another wrapper
//now we use an interface MyNetObject implementing the method getTarget(), but
//also an abstract class would be possible (with a more complex getTarget-method):
MyNetObject netObject = (MyNetObject) ois.readObject();   //Or use another parser...
if(netObject.getTarget()=="Thread1ClassANDThread2Class"){
    thread1.activateSync(netObject);        //notify...  
    thread2.activateSync(netObject);        //...both threads!
}
else if(netObject.getTarget()=="Thread1Class"){
    thread1.activate(netObject);        //give thread1 a notification
}
else if(netObject.getTarget()=="Thread2Class"){
    thread2.activate(netObject);        //give thread2 a notification
}
else {//do something else...}
```

Don't forget to synchronize the "activateSync(netObject)"-method, but only if you want to do any changements to the object (you don't need to synchronize readings, only writings):

```
public void activateSync(MyNetObject netObject){
    synchronize(netObject){
        //do whatever you wanna do with the object...the other thread will always get the actual object!
    }
}
```

That's easy, fast, consistent...and fully object oriented. Hope you'll get the idea. ;)

**UPDATE:**

It's important to understand that streams or reader are actually also "parser". With one important difference: Streams are (usually) network driven classes, which are used to write and read any kind of data - except chars. While reader are be used to read any kind of text/chars. So your proper implementation would be this: Read the incoming packets with some streams and then just store the data into an appropriate object. Then you have a generic object which you can use in any kind of reader. If you have just a picture to read, you could try the parser `readUTF()` in the class `ObjectInputStream`(http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) which yields a string:

```
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(/*yourBasicInputStream*/);
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bis);
String string = ois.readUTF();   //Or another usable parser/method
XmlParser1.read(string);      //for reads there is...
XmlParser2.read(string);      //...no synchronisation needed!
```

Now, the only thing left is to teach the parser how to read that string. While the object string itself could be regarded a the "sink". If this doesn't work for you, just find another parser/method to create the "sink" object.

Please note that the solutions discussed here - using the class ObjectInputStream with an appropriate parser - work in many cases, also with big data (then you just slice a file of i.e. 1GB into several string/object "packets" before sending over the net, the same like torrents do). But it won't work with video/audio streaming, where you may have packet drops and need anyway totally different solutions (this is a science per se: http://www.google.ch/search?q=video+stream+packet+drop).

Answer (score 0):

I tried pulling the otiginal input Stream into an Apache Commons TeeInputStream to create an OutputStream.
http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/input/TeeInputStream.html

As the OutputStream to be written to by the IeeInputStream, I used a java PipedOutputStream.

I connected this PipedOutputStream to a java PipedInputStream.

This allowed me to read the TeeInputStream and the PipedInputStream. Not sure if it will work for you, or if it will at least provided the next step.

I created a ReaderThread class to check if i could read them in parallel:

```
  private static class ReaderThread extends Thread
  {
    InputStream inStream;
    int threadId;
    public ReaderThread(int threadId, InputStream inStream)
    {
      this.inStream = inStream;
      this.threadId = threadId;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
      try
      {
        int c = inStream.read();
        while (c != -1)
        {
          System.out.println("From ("+threadId+ ") "+c);
          c = inStream.read();
        }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }
```

This was then driven from the following code:

```
InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
PipedInputStream pipedInStream = new PipedInputStream();
OutputStream pipedOutStream = new PipedOutputStream(pipedInStream);
TeeInputStream tin = new TeeInputStream(inStream,
  pipedOutStream);

ReaderThread firstThread = new ReaderThread(1,tin);
ReaderThread secondThread = new ReaderThread(2,pipedInStream);

firstThread.start();
secondThread.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of unclear what's going on inside XmlParse1 and XmlParser2, but assuming that they actually care about the ultimate XML data and not the InputStream bytes, i would switch to the StAX XMLEvent api.  you can make both of the parsers implement [XMLEventConsumer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/util/XMLEventConsumer.html).  Then, you just have an outer loop which parses the actual stream and passes the events to the consumers:

```
public void parseXml(InputStream stream) {
  XMLEventReader reader = ...; // convert stream into XMLEventReader

  XMLConsumer[] consumers = new XMLConsumer[]{new XmlParser1(), new XmlParser2()};

  while(reader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
    for(XMLConsumer consumer : consumers) {
      consumer.add(event));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it "The API of those consumers are inherently non cooperative."  So don't try to make them, KEEP THE ISOLATION and give them what they want.  Separate input Streams.

Have a thread reading the real input stream and writing to two output streams.

Then make input streams from those output streams, you can do this with Piped Streams

> pipedInputStream1 = new PipedInputStream(pipedOutputStream1);

and

> ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream) byteOutputStream1).toByteArray());